# Angular2 Rc4 to Rc5 Migration: unable to load website (traceur/forms)

Tags: angular, typescript, migration, angular-cli

I upgraded my ng2 app today from RC4 to RC5 using [this](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/) and will upgrade from RC5 to C7 later. I am getting annoying error

> http://localhost:5001/ember-cli-live-reload.js Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:5001/traceur Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) zone.js:344 Unhandled
>   Promise rejection: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:5001/traceur     Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)
>   loading http://localhost:5001/traceur
>         at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:5001/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:636:29)
>         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:5001/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:225:37)
>         at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:5001/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:47)
>         at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:5001/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:293:33)    Error
>   loading http://localhost:5001/traceur     Unable to load transpiler to
>   transpile http://localhost:5001/vendor/@angular/forms/index.js    Error
>   loading http://localhost:5001/vendor/@angular/forms/index.js as
>   "@angular/forms" from http://localhost:5001/app/app.module.js ; Zone:
>    ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404
>   Not Found) loading http://localhost:5001/traceur(…) (SystemJS) XHR
>   error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5001/traceur   Error:
>   XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5001/traceur
>         at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:5001/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:636:29)
>         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:5001/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:225:37)
>         at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:5001/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:47)
>         at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:5001/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:293:33)    Error
>   loading http://localhost:5001/traceur     Unable to load transpiler to
>   transpile http://localhost:5001/vendor/@angular/forms/index.js    Error
>   loading http://localhost:5001/vendor/@angular/forms/index.js as
>   "@angular/forms" from
>   http://localhost:5001/app/app.module.jsconsoleError @ zone.js:344
>   zone.js:346 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: (SystemJS) XHR error
>   (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5001/traceur(…)consoleError @
>   zone.js:346

the culprit lines are

> Unable to load transpiler to transpile
>   http://localhost:5001/vendor/@angular/forms/index.js
>
> Error loading http://localhost:5001/vendor/@angular/forms/index.js as
>   "@angular/forms" from http://localhost:5001/app/app.module.js

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing } from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { FactoryFormComponent } from "./factory/factory-form.component";
import { SupplierFormComponent } from "./supplier/supplier-form.component";
import { BusinessAreaFormComponent } from './business-area/business-area-form.component';
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";

import { FactoryService } from "./factory/factory.service";
import { SupplierService } from "./supplier/supplier.service";
import { AppService } from "./shared/app.service";
import { UtilityService } from "./shared/utility.service";
import { HomeService } from "./home/home.service";
import { BusinessAreaService } from './business-area/business-area.service';


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, routing, FormsModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, FactoryFormComponent, SupplierFormComponent, BusinessAreaFormComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [AppService, UtilityService, FactoryService, SupplierService, HomeService, BusinessAreaService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**packages.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "xxxx",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "systemjs": "0.19.38",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.6",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "cucumber": "^1.2.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^0.6.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

**system-config.ts**

```
// SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
    // Angular specific barrels.
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/forms',

    // Thirdparty barrels.
    'rxjs',
    'ng2-bootstrap',

    // App specific barrels.
    'app',
    'app/shared',
    'app/factory',
    'app/data',
    'app/supplier',
    'app/home',
    'app/business-area',
    'app/contact',
  'app/relationship',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
    cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
    map: {
        '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
        'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
        'main': 'main.js',
        'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
        'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js'
    },
    packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
// Angular-CLI build configuration
// This file lists all the node_modules files that will be used in a build
// Also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function (defaults) {
    return new Angular2App(defaults, {
        vendorNpmFiles: [
          'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
          'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
          'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
          'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
          'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
          'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
          '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
          'ng2-bootstrap/**/*.js',
          'moment/moment.js',
          'bootstrap/dist/**/*'
        ]
    });
};
```

I can't seem to get my head around that why it is unable to load Forms. It was working with RC4 for sure...any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to migrate to RC05 from RC04 I believe you have to use older version of the forms module

```
"@angular/forms": "version 0.3.0"
```

I would suggest to directly try to update to Angular2 version 2.0.0.

Comment: what do you mean directly upgrade Angular 2 to 2.0.0? i think the latest is RC7 is it not?

Comment: @KamranPervaiz Angular2 was released some days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Angular team has changed their policy regarding ES version in their packages. In the past, you had ES5 scripts and everything worked as a charm. Currently, the files inside packages are written in ES6. SystemJS finds `import {something} from 'somewhere';` inside and tries to transpile script to ES5 (This is purpose of traceur).

Solution:
Change SystemJS configuration or setup traceur to transpile scripts in client's browser.

I prefer the first method, because it is faster and easier to setup:

system-config.ts:

```
...
const packages: any = {
  'rxjs' : {main: 'Rx'},
  '@angular/core' : {main: 'bundles/core.umd.js'},
  '@angular/common' : {main: 'bundles/common.umd.js'},
  '@angular/upgrade' : {main: 'bundles/upgrade.umd.js'},
  '@angular/compiler' : {main: 'bundles/compiler.umd.js'},
  '@angular/forms' : {main: 'bundles/forms.umd.js'},
  '@angular/router' : {main: 'bundles/router.umd.js'},
  '@angular/platform-browser' : {main: 'bundles/platform-browser.umd.js'},
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {main: 'bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js'},
  '@angular/http' : {main: 'bundles/http.umd.min.js'},
...
```

The downside of this strategy is that you have whole package inside one file. This can make debugging harder.

Also, please remember, that you WILL NOT be allowed to access APIs marked as private by angular team. This is also the recent change.

More to find out here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: umd.js? is this new extension? I am working with angular-cli. will it work?

Comment: I am also on angular-cli. UMD is short version of Universal Module Definition. This is just a sign, that module can be imported both via RequireJS and NodeJS. More info: https://github.com/umdjs/umd